# Rails belongs_to to both ways

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model Ticket and a model Receipt. Receipt has attribute ticket_id.

receipt.rb

```
belongs_to :ticket
```

One receipt has always 1 ticket only and 1 ticket has one receipt only.

Now I can call receipt.ticket. But I can't call ticket.receipt.

Is there a way to achieve that without adding receipt_id attribute to Ticket?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[has_one](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_one)

receipt.rb

```
belongs_to :ticket
```

ticket.rb

```
has_one :receipt
#has_one :receipt, class_name: "Receipt", foreign_key: "ticket_id"
```

..

```
#receipt.ticket =>  Returns the associated ticket. nil is returned if none is found.
#ticket.receipt =>  Returns the associated receipt. nil is returned if none is found.
```

Comment: If it's not work then you can explicitly say that association for which class and foreign_key this association be called as `has_one :receipt, class_name: "Receipt", foreign_key: "ticket_id"`

Comment: @Catmal Feel free to accept/upvote answer if it helped you, aslo for future SO searchers.

Comment: Ah no was not the case column is ticket_id which is rails default. Must have been something else. Anyway works now I'll accept as soon as it's possible

Comment: @Catmal Sometime it needs to call association explicitly with the join_key between associated models, by  providing class and foregin_key, in your case it was supposed that `has_one` was not working that's why i thought it's good idea to explicitly call it, otherwise by rails convention it's automatically understand the association, anyway thanks.

Comment: If this is a Rails 5 app the belongs_to association `receipt.ticket ` will throw a validation error instead of returning nil.  belongs_to now has `required: true` as a default behavior.

Comment: @Tom If you knew this already then you should also aware of that `receipt` won't allow to create any record without `ticket` as it's `required: true` in rails 5. hence there is no chance to be record created without `ticket` therefore there is no any chance to throw any error for `nil`. :D.

Comment: @Gabbar It is very much a possibility that a ticket could be destroyed outside of ActiveRecord. In that scenario, the next time the receipt is validated it would fail the association and raise an error.  My comment is not about how we would get to a state where a receipt did not have a ticket; my comment is about how your comment:  `Returns the associated ticket. nil is returned if none is found.` is not true in a standard Rails 5 setup.

Answer (score 0):

In ticket.rb, add:

`has_one :receipt`